# How to exclude (ignore) android build variants in gradle kts

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-kts

During migration build script from groovy to kotlin I met problem with excluding build variants.

In groovy it's pretty easy:

```
android {
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.name == "lorempisum") {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

but in kotlin similar thing does not work. It seems to be ok in android studio, but during compilation it throws `Unresolved reference: isIgnore`

```
android {
    variantFilter {
        if (buildType.name == "lorempisum") {
            isIgnore = true
        }
    }
}
```

from the other side this reports `Unresolved reference: setIgnore`, but works during compilation

```
android {
    variantFilter {
        if (buildType.name == "lorempisum") {
            this.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody has idea how do it in right way?

I'm using kotlin 1.3.72, android studio 4.0.1 and gradle 6.5.1

---- EDIT ----

I fix example `ignore` -> `isIgnore` in second block, it also not works

Comment: Maybe the problem is that android studio uses different sources to code completion and other in runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soultion is `ignore = true` with a little deatil.

This works if you keep in top-level `build.gradle.kts` this line:

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`

and not really only on `buildSrc` on this:

`implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [beforeVariants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#kts) block:

```
androidComponents {
    beforeVariants { variantBuilder ->
        // To check for a certain build type, use variantBuilder.buildType == "<buildType>"
        if (variantBuilder.productFlavors.containsAll(listOf("api" to "minApi21", "mode" to "demo"))) {
            // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
            variantBuilder.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first update to the last version of android studio and the plugins.
And try this

```
variantFilter {
    this.ignore = name == "lorempisum"
}
```

Comment: Using this `this.ignore` seems to be correct in IDE, but during compilation, it again throws `Unresolved reference: ignore`. I'm using latest stable android studio 4.0.1 and it not works on both gradle 6.5.1 and 6.6.1

Comment: Ok. I'm on android studio 4.1.0 RC2 and gradle 6.5. This gradle Kotlin DSL is better supported on 4.1 or 4.2.