# isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled not works in gradle kotlin dsl / kts

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-kts

To enable desugaring in our android-library module we must put this in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
  }
}
```

But we have all scripts migrated to gradle kotlin dsl, so the problem occurs in `build.gradle.kts` in all three ways:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}
```

```
configure<BaseExtension> {
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}
```

```
android {
    if (this is com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryExtension<*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *>) {
        buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Every time it throws `Unresolved reference: isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled`.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I switch to the newer android plugin version (4.1.0-rc02) it theoretically works. IDE says it's bad syntax, but it works during compilation.

```
if (this is com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryExtension<*, *, *, *, *>) {
    compileOptions.isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
}
```

However, it's not an ideal solution

----- FINAL SOLUTION -----

Solution is similar to [How to exclude (ignore) android build variants in gradle kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635713/how-to-exclude-ignore-android-build-variants-in-gradle-kts/63899943#63899943)

It wasn't work because of missing line in top-level `build.gradle.kts` this line:

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`

Comment: Right. for me setting build tools to `4.0.1` and gradle version to `gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` worked. thanks.

Comment: also I used `coreLib...` instead of `isCoreLib...` due to `4.0.1` and also I had to change kotlin version (due to some other jetifier errors in my case) as well to newer and compatible version. so had to change bunch of things.I am setting up a few months old project so facing these errors.

Answer (score 51):

If you're using Android Gradle Plugin version >= 4.1, use:

```
isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
```

For versions before that, use:

```
coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
```

Comment: for version 4.0 if you use `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
` then compiler will say `Unresolved reference: coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled`